# How to serialize nested message with msg-pack in cpp?

Tags: c++, serialization, nested, maps, msgpack

How can I serialize a structure where a map is nested in a map - like the message below - using msg pack in cpp?:

`{"string": "string",
 "string": {"string":  int, "string":  int, "string":  int}
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:-

```
struct s{
std::map< std::string, std::string> m;
std::map< std::string, std::map<std::string, std::int> > l;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! The idea was correct. To make it work with msgpack, I needed a few changes:


`struct S1 {
    string subject;
    vector<unordered_map<string, string>>ref_data;
    MSGPACK_DEFINE_MAP(subject,ref_data);
};`